# Is there a way to detect when an applet has been closed?

Tags: java, web, event-handling, applet, japplet

So I have a game in a JApplet, and I make a new thread that loops the background music continuously. However, when I close the window the tab that the applet is in, the music keeps playing. It only stops when I exit the browser. Is there a way to tell the music to stop playing when I close the tab?

Comment: The answer is in a now deleted answer by @Asier.  I am hoping they will undelete it so I can upvote, but basically, look to the `stop()`/`destroy()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to detect this. And you can invoke applet methods from javascript.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html